# Delete ROW that a namedRange is Associated With in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

I know I can delete the actual namedRange, but that is not what I am looking for. I have a cell that has a namedRange associated with it. I want the script to determine what row this cell resides in and delete that entire row.

Doing something like below only deletes the namedRange, not the row it is associated with. Any ideas how I would go about doing that? Thanks!

```
var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getNamedRanges();
    namedRanges('namedRange1').remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function delRow(name) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rg=ss.getRangeByName(name);
  rg.getSheet().deleteRow(rg.getRow());
}
```

Comment: I think that when the situations that the named range has several rows are also supposed, it might be useful for OP and other users.

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand what your saying.

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. The named range can include several rows and columns. In your script, the 1st row of the named range is deleted. When the named range has several rows, only 1st row is deleted. I thought that OP might want to delete all rows of named range. So as additional information, I proposed it. But if I misunderstood this situation, I have to apologize.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Currently I do not have the need to delete more than one row, but that could certainly come in handy in the future. Thanks!